# django.db.utils.Database error running manage.py syncdb in new project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-syncdb

I am running Django 1.4, Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04. I started a new app and created a postgres 9.1 database for it. Entered the db details in `settings.py` and ran `python manage.py syncdb`. I included 'south' in installed apps then got the following error. Even after removing south, I keep getting the same error. I have not created any apps yet in the project.
The main error is:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column django_content_type.name does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."na...
```

The complete traceback is:

```
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 110, in handle_noargs
emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 189, in emit_post_sync_signal
interactive=interactive, db=db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 35, in create_permissions
ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(klass)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 42, in get_for_model
defaults = {'name': smart_unicode(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 134, in get_or_create
return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 442, in get_or_create
return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
num = len(clone)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in __len__
self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column django_content_type.name does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."na...
                                       ^
```

Comment: Try to drop and create database. Second idea is to try using Django version 1.7, or 1.8 it will work on python 2.7.

Comment: What's on your settings.py?